# Is there any implementation of Recursive Auto Encoders in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am looking for the implementation of Recursive Auto Encoders (RAE) in tensor flow python. I want to model English sentence representations from a sequence to sequence neural network model. RAE is proven to be one of the best choice to represent sentences in recent machine learning approaches. I googled and didn't find any tensorflow Recursive Auto Encoders (RAE) implementation resource, please help. And if there is no implementation of RAE in tensorflow then please share the links of Theano.